# How to automate downloading recent file uploaded in Google Drive folder?

Tags: ubuntu, scripting, api, google-drive

I want to automate the downloading of files that are daily uploaded to a shared Google Drive folder.

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287651/download-a-spreadsheet-from-google-docs-using-python